# Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I have recently switched over from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04, and I have been missing out on quite a bit of software. The reason I switched over to Ubuntu was primarily for security concerns -- on Windows, computers on my home network can remotely access my computer, and they had. On Ubuntu they cannot do so.

My question is: If I have both Windows and Ubuntu running with the option to boot either one, will I still be exposed to the security risks and vulnerabilities that come with Windows? Will files on my Ubuntu OS be affected/accessible at all if someone *was* able to gain remote access to my Windows OS? Or would the two exist completely separate from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question of yours:

"Will files on my Ubuntu OS be affected/accessible at all if someone was able to gain remote access to my Windows OS? Or would the two exist completely separate from each other?"

If someone gets access to your computer through Windows OS, your Linux files can be accessed as well.

While the attacker can easily read the Linux files, writing to it (for malicious script/attack) to the Linux partition won't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

When running Ubuntu, it is a completly seperated environment, except the hard drive.

Incase of hackers, once they do somehow get access to your computer, they would have access to all files, both Windows and Ubuntu partitions. So if a hacker for e.g. gets access to the computer while it's running Windows, they would also have access to the Ubuntu partiton. Therfore I suggest encrypting both drives if you want total security.

Also, I'd like to let you know that Windows has the ability to turn off the remote control option.

Comment: You mean just through Computer --> properties --> turn off remote access? I have tried taking many measures to secure my Windows OS and my computer has still been left vulnerable. But I do not face those same issues on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, this is how you stop remote access. As I have answered you question I'd appreciate it if you would mark this answer as correct.